# A semi-simple connected algebraic group is perfect

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

> Let $G$ be an algebraic group over an algebrically closed field $\mathbb{K}$ of caracteristic $0$.
>   We say that $G$ est semi-simple if every connected, solvable, normal, closed subgroup of $G$ is equal to $\{1\}$.

My purpose is to show that if $G$ is semi-simple then $G$ is perfect (i.e. $G$ is equal to its commutator group $(G,G)$.
I already found a proof in P. Tauvel AND R. W. T. Yu "Lie Algebras and Algebraic Groups" book, but I wanted to make one that does not use Lie Algebras.

My first idea was to consider the group quotient $G/(G,G)$ and show that this group is isomorphic to $\{1\}$. But all I know about this group is that it is connected and commutative(so solvable).

Any hint or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

K. Y.

Comment: I doubt there is any easy proof of this that does not use Lie algebras.  The essential characteristic of semisimple algebraic groups is that they have semisimple Lie algebras, well understood objects whose defining features can be carried up to $G$.  Also, this is true for arbitrary characteristic algebraic groups.

Comment: Using the quotient $G/(G,G)$, my main idea was to find an injective map from $G/(G,G)$ to $G$ so we can view this quotient as a subgroup of $G$. Then, adding the fact that this subgroup is closed and normal and since $G$ is semi-simple, we get that it is trivial. But I tried and I didn't found how